# Is it possible to put Eclipse GWT project under EGit?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, egit

Is it possible to put Eclipse GWT project under EGit?

If I select an option "Use or create repository in parent folder of a project", Eclipse says "Creation of repositories in the Eclipse workspace is not recommended" and does not allow me to go further.

If I deselect this option, it moves the project files into a separate folder of Git repository and breaks the classpath. For example, Web App Libraries entry remains pointing to the old place and does not fix it upon recreate.

Trap! How to get out?

Comment: What if when you create your project, you provide the external folder in a git repo as the location instead of using the default location?

Answer (score 2):

When it shows that warning, you need to hit the "Create Repository" button at the bottom of the dialog.  That will allow you to select your project as your repo and use Finish.

See [EGit User Guide/Repos](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/One_page#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse) for a discussion on why it's better to have an external repo.

PW

Answer (score 0):

You have to select project folder in the project view, then right click 'Team>Add'. 'Team>Add to index' in newer eclipse versions. Make a commit and the Web App Libraries fixes itself.